# PLINQ Parallel issue

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, plinq

I have a problem related with the PLINQ. Imagine that I have a list of products `Queue<ClientProductContainer> _products = Queue<ClientProductContainer>()` for a costumer, lets say 30 products for the customer A, and I want to insert them using Parallel PLINQ:

```
    var clientProductsContainer = new ConcurrentQueue<ClientProductContainer>();

   _products
   .AsParallel()
   .AsUnordered()
   .ForAll(product=>
   {
        product.PrepareToBulkSave();
        clientProductsContainer.Enqueue(MapProduct(product));
   });
```

All these products are different, with different codes and different prices (thats why I have the statement `product.PrepareToBulkSave()`, because I need to insert the prices at the same time as the products. After mapping the objets to my domain classes, I want to call a method to save them in my SQL Server database. The problem is that not all products are being inserted, but the number o products inserted are equal to 30. I have a virtual machine with 4 cores, and the result of inserted products is as follows:

- Product10 - Inserted 4 times
- Product11 - Inserted 4 times
- Product12 - Inserted 4 times
- Product13 - Inserted 3 times
- Product21 - Inserted 4 times
- Product22 - Inserted 4 times
- Product23 - Inserted 3 times
- Product24 - Inserted 4 times

With this result, I am missing products 1 to 9, 14 to 20 and 25 to 30. This only happens when I'm using parallel and the machine is at 100% and the memory is at 95% capacity.
Can someone help me understand this problem?

Comment: I don't see any issues in the code you posted. Could you post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: What's the code inside `PrepareToBulkSave` and `MapProduct`?